# MVC trying to pass model from razor view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So my story is that I am having trouble with the post to the controller, the view seems to work fine. When the postback happens the tm.BookId is 0 (should be 1) and the list count is 0.   First I will display the model:

```
 public class TransferModel
{
    public TransferModel()
    {
        cbItems = new List<CheckBoxItem>();
    }
    public List<CheckBoxItem> cbItems {get;set;}
    public int BookId;
    public class CheckBoxItem
    {
        public int AttributeId { get; set; }
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The Controller part:

```
public ActionResult AddAttributes(int id = 0)
    {
        db.transMod.BookId = id;
        BookInfo book = db.BookInfoes.Find(id);
        var latts = db.BookAtts.ToList();
        foreach (BookAtt ba in latts)
        {
            db.transMod.cbItems.Add(new TransferModel.CheckBoxItem { Attribute = ba.Attribute, AttributeId = ba.BookAttId, Selected = false });
        }
        List<BookAtt> atInList = book.BookAtts.ToList();
        foreach (TransferModel.CheckBoxItem cb in db.transMod.cbItems)
        {
            if (atInList.Exists(item => item.Attribute == cb.Attribute))
                cb.Selected = true;
        }

        return View(db.transMod);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddAttributes(TransferModel tm)
    {
       List<BookAtt> atPool = db.BookAtts.ToList();
       BookInfo book = db.BookInfoes.Find(tm.BookId);
       foreach (TransferModel.CheckBoxItem sel in tm.cbItems)
        {
            if (sel.Selected)
            book.BookAtts.Add(atPool.Find(item1 => item1.Attribute == sel.Attribute));
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AddAttributes");
    }`enter code here`
```

And finally the view:

```
 @model BrightStar.Models.TransferModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Update Attributes";
}
<h2>Add Attributes</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table>
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.BookId)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.cbItems)

@foreach (var itm in Model.cbItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(mo => itm.AttributeId)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(mo => itm.Selected)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(mo => itm.Attribute)</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"  />
    </p>
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Is this as simple as missing the form?

Comment: No, he has it there. `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {`

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML here?

Answer (score 1):

Model binding doesn't happen automatically, items needs to be in certain format to get binded to list properties in POST actions. Check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspxm=bv.45512109,d.dmQ) out.

Try checking out the value of BookId property in the DOM to confirm it is 1, otherwise it should bind normally.

Comment: this doesn't link to anything.

Comment: the this doesn't link to anything. In the view, it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your model's properties in helpers to correctly generate names for your controls:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.cbItems)
```

should be

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cbItems)
```